# Setting entry/leave conditions in step function in R

Tags: r, regression, glm

I am using `step` with `test = "Chisq"` argument to perform stepwise logistic regression. However I cannot find any argument for the entry/leave significance level. From my output I can guess that it is set to 0.15. Is there a way to specify this level? If no, what would be the second choice for stepwise regression with such functionality?

Kuba

Comment: The documentation for `?step` clearly says "Choose a model by AIC in a Stepwise Algorithm". Thus, there is no significance involved here, rather the lowest AIC

Comment: The `test` parameter gets passed to `drop1` or `add1`. Their help page states this is only used to provide information in the output rather than used for model selection.